How to integrate $\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1+x^{2}}}dx$?
How to integrate $$\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1+x^{2}}}dx$$ ?
I evaluated the integral $$\int\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}dx$$ quickly.
I just substituted $x=\tan(y)$ then $dx=\sec^{2}(y)dy$.
Therefore the integral is becoming quite easy.
$$\int\frac{1+\tan(y)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}(y)}}\sec^{2}(y)dy$$
$$=\int\frac{1+\tan(y)}{\sec(y)}\sec^{2}(y)dy$$
$$=\int(1+\tan(y))(\sec(y))dy$$
$$=\int\sec(y)dy+\int\tan(y)\sec(y)dy$$
Now it is quite easy and I am not going further in detail about this integral.
But for the integral $$\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1+x^{2}}}dx$$ if I substitute $x=\tan(y)$, then the integral will become :
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{1+\tan(y)}{1+\tan^{2}(y)}}\sec^{2}(y)dy$$
Therefore the integral will be
$$\int\left(\sqrt{1+\tan(y)}\right)\sec(y)dy$$
Now I also can't apply IBP(Integration By Parts) technique here.
Then how to integrate ?
If anyone can solve it then kindly inform me.

You will need elliptic integrals.

Mathematica gives the result $-\frac{(1-i) \sqrt{(2+2 i)-(2-2 i) x} \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}} \left(E\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(-1-i) (x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-i\right)-F\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(-1-i) (x+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|-i\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x+i}}}$

Updated for simpler

$$I=\int\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1+x^{2}}}\,dx$$
$$x=\sinh(t) \qquad \implies \qquad I=\int \sqrt{1+\sinh (t)}\,dt$$
$$t=i\,u \qquad \implies \qquad I=i \int \sqrt{1+i \sin (u)} \,du$$
But
$$\sin(u)=1-2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{u}{2}\right)$$
$$u=\frac{\pi }{2}-2 v\qquad \implies \qquad I=-2i\int  \sqrt{(1+i)-2 i \sin ^2(v)} \,dv$$
Here arrives the elliptic integral.
$$I=2 \sqrt{-(1+i)}\,\,E\left(\left.v\right|(1+i)\right)$$
Edit
Looking at all these substitutions, the shortest would have been
$$x=i \cos (2 v)$$ leading to
$$I=-2i\,\int \sqrt{1+i \cos (2 v)}\,dv=-2i\int  \sqrt{(1+i)-2 i \sin ^2(v)} \,dv$$
